# ValueError when using ColumnTransformer() in an Sklearn Pipeline - Using custom class of Spacy for GloveVectorizer

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, spacy

I've got a dataset with multiple text columns and a target column. I'm trying to use a Cusom Class of Spacy to use Glove embeddings for my text column, and also trying to do it with a Pipeline. But I'm getting a ValueError. Following is my code:

```
data_features = df.copy()[["title", "description"]]
train_data, test_data, train_target, test_target = train_test_split(data_features, df['target'], test_size = 0.1)
```

I created this custom class to use glove embeddings. I got the code from [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-triune-pipeline-for-three-major-transformers-in-nlp-18c14e20530).

```
class SpacyVectorTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, nlp):
        self.nlp = nlp
        self.dim = 300

    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return [self.nlp(text).vector for text in X]
```

Loading the nlp model:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

This is the column transformer that I'm trying to use in my pipeline:

```
col_preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        [
            ('title_glove', SpacyVectorTransformer(nlp), 'title'),
            ('description_glove', SpacyVectorTransformer(nlp), 'description'),
        ],
        remainder='drop',
        n_jobs=1
        )
```

Here is my pipeline:

```
pipeline_glove = Pipeline([
    ('col_preprocessor', col_preprocessor), 
    ('classifier', LogisticRegression())
])
```

When I run the fit method, I get the error that follows:

```
pipeline_glove.fit(train_data, train_target)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-219-8543ea744205> in <module>
----> 1 pipeline_glove.fit(train_data, train_target)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    328         """
    329         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 330         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    331         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    332                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    294                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
    295                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 296                 **fit_params_steps[name])
    297             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    298             # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 355         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    356 
    357     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    738     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    739         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 740             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    741         else:
    742             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    549 
    550         self._update_fitted_transformers(transformers)
--> 551         self._validate_output(Xs)
    552 
    553         return self._hstack(list(Xs))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _validate_output(self, result)
    410                 raise ValueError(
    411                     "The output of the '{0}' transformer should be 2D (scipy "
--> 412                     "matrix, array, or pandas DataFrame).".format(name))
    413 
    414     def _validate_features(self, n_features, feature_names):

ValueError: The output of the 'title_glove' transformer should be 2D (scipy matrix, array, or pandas DataFrame).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error message tells you, what you need to fix.

> ValueError: The output of the 'title_glove' transformer should be 2D
> (scipy matrix, array, or pandas DataFrame).

But what you are returning with your current transformer (SpacyVectorTransformer) is a list. You can fix it, by turning the list into a pandas DataFrame for instance like this:

```
import pandas as pd

class SpacyVectorTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, nlp):
        self.nlp = nlp
        self.dim = 300

    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return pd.DataFrame([self.nlp(text).vector for text in X])
```

Next time, please also provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your provided code, there are no imports as well as no DataFrame called "df".